# Should I make the interface methods return Task if some consumers cannot implement them?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am learning Xamarin.Forms and right now I am reading about shared libraries.
If I create an interface for IO operations, should I make the interface methods return `Task` or `Task<...>` even if some platform specific projects (iOS, Android, UWP) may not have asynchronous built-in methods to invoke.
I know that wrapping synchronous IO methods with `Task` or `Task<...>` is not a good idea.

Or should I make the interface methods synchronous? It makes the built-in asynchronous methods must be invoked synchronously -- it is also not a good idea.

Comment: Return asynchronous versions. If someone cannot await it asynchronously, they can always wait synchronously. I don't know if xamarin.forms has synchronization context, but if so, your library must use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to support synchronous scenarios.

Comment: Given that these different types of implementations need to *behave radically differently* and be called *radically differently* by any consumers, they really shouldn't implement the same interface to begin with.  You have different behaviors that different consumers will use in one of two different ways. Have an interface for each (externally visible) behavior.

Comment: @FCin That is providing *numerous* opportunities for lots of different types of bugs, for both the authors and consumers of the library.

Comment: @FCin Given how inaccurate your comment is, would you mind removing it so we don't spread misinformation?

Comment: @Servy This statement is so vague I don't even know how to answer that.

Comment: @mason Please point out which part of my statement is incorrect. If we consider the same method, but with synchronous and asynchronous versions of IO, we can remove duplicated code by providing only asynchronous versions. We can avoid possible deadlock by disabling callback to calling thread by using `.ConfigureAwait(false)`

Comment: @FCin You're just introducing more opportunities for issues. From [Stephen Cleary's article](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html): `Using ConfigureAwait(false) to avoid deadlocks is a dangerous practice. You would have to use ConfigureAwait(false) for every await in the transitive closure of all methods called by the blocking code, including all third- and second-party code. Using ConfigureAwait(false) to avoid deadlock is at best just a hack). As the title of this post points out, the better solution is “Don’t block on async code”.`

Comment: @mason Please try to at least understand sentences you are quoting. _"the better solution is “Don’t block on async code”"_. The point is, we are talking about a scenario where the is no possible way of "not blocking" async code, so `.ConfigureAwait(false)` is not a hack, but a way of removing duplicated code. If you understand internal workings of async/await, then you are 100% able to provide working library that exposes only asynchronous versions of your methods. Every line of code can introduce bugs and be dangerous if you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: @FCin It is absolutely a hack. Nothing you've said invalidates what Stephen said. Servy pointed out the proper solution: have different interfaces for sync and async. In your quest to remove "duplicate code" (note it's not really duplicated because you call async code differently) you're going to introduce bugs. Stephen literally [wrote the book on async](https://www.amazon.com/Concurrency-Cookbook-Asynchronous-Multithreaded-Programming/dp/1449367569). Do you think you understand the internal workings better than he? Your advice is directly contradicting what he's said.

Comment: @FCin Yes, it's *technically possible*, but it's extremely likely to have bugs, either in the implementation of the library, or for the caller, because of just how difficult it is to write the code using such an approach correctly. As such, it's pretty much always a bad idea.  It's also not at all true to say that it's the only possible approach. For starters, the question doesn't provide enough information to assert that they even have a requirement of calling asynchronous methods in synchronous context, but if they did, there are still other approaches to do that, each with their trade offs.

Comment: @mason I know Stephen's articles very well and I know that your qoute makes less sense if you actually look at the context of this article. It is supposed to explain why it is better to go async all the way than to wait for async methods synchronously. Environment in which you run the code changes everything.

Comment: @mason Surely implementing both sync/async versions of each method is safer, but don't write _"Given how inaccurate your comment is"_ when my comment makes sense and is a reasonable solution to a given problem.

Comment: @FCin I do not consider the need to ensure all 2nd and 3rd party code properly does `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to be any kind of a reasonable solution. You're teaching bad habits to others by making statements like that. Async is hard enough for people to learn without needing to sift through such misleading statements.

Comment: @FCin Your comment is inaccurate in that you state it's the only possible solution, when there are in fact numerous possible solutions.  It's also not "reasonable" because it's suggesting a very poor solution, among the various options at hand.  Due to a lack of specifics, it's difficult to be sure what an ideal solution would be, but it's pretty unlikely that yours is going to be the best option.

Comment: @Servy First of all I've never stated that my solution is the only possible solution or that it is even the best one. Secondly, depending on what type of methods you want to support, you can be sure about whether they internally implement `.ConfigureAwait` or not.

Comment: @FCin You posted a comment stating the solution that they *must use*, despite it not being a solution that the must actually use, or even one that's desirable for them to use.  Next, it's *not* in fact trivial to figure out what methods do or do not use the current synchronization context (or whether that behavior will ever change in the future).  If it's a method in your code, it's not always trivial to tell and can often be *very* difficult to determine, and in code that's *not* yours it's very often not documented at all.

Comment: @Servy They must use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` _if_ they decide go with my approach. Not in general.

Comment: @FCin Not even then.  There are numerous possible ways of synchronously waiting on an asynchronous operation without causing bugs.  Trying to use `ConfigureAwait` is a fairly poor option *even among possible solutions to that problem*.  It's not even the best solution to *that* problem, let alone the only one.  Not only is it bug prone, due to how easy it is to make a mistake, there are numerous things that may be going on in the implementation (or a 3rd party method called by it) that `ConfigureAwait` doesn't solve (you need to ensure nothing waits on the current synchronization context).

Comment: @Servy Then please suggest a better way of waiting synchronously for a asynchronous call without creating additional tasks in environment with synchronization context.

Comment: @FCin Well they probably *shouldn't be putting themselves in that situation in the first place*.  That's almost certainly the correct solution here. But if you insist, personally I prefer changing the current synchronization context to the default context (if you know nothing in the implementation of that method has a genuine use of the current context), or you can create a message pump to pump messages to the context (if you do actually need to send messages to the current context within the implementation), and you could have an asynchronous implementation that doesn't use `await` at all.

Comment: @Servy I thought about it and you are right. When it comes to 3rd party libraries, my approach would eventually fail. Also it requires a lot of discipline since you have to configure every task in the chain. Writing both sync and async versions would probably be a much better option.